# How can I perform a rolling calculation on a vector?

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, zoo, quantmod

I want to make a rolling calculation on a vector.

I'm using the `ifelse` statement to write it however am getting a bit caught up, my current data is:

```
Prob <- 0.6
Bet <- 10
Spread <- Bet
Trans <- 0.998

> IndTest
           N225.Open    Close     High      Low    S.High      S.Low       S.OC
2007-01-04  17322.50 17353.67 17379.46 17315.76  56.96094   6.740234   31.16992
2007-01-05  17315.54 17091.59 17327.13 17011.10  11.59180 304.439453 -223.94922
2007-01-09  17018.89 17237.77 17261.03 16983.97 242.13867  34.919922  218.87891
2007-01-10  17192.42 16942.40 17199.42 16847.57   7.00000 344.849610 -250.01953
2007-01-11  16958.57 16838.17 17057.45 16758.46  98.87891 200.109374 -120.40039
           D.Pos D.Neg   H.S.Avg  L.S.Avg P.D.Up P.D.Dn     P.Bal
2007-01-04     1     0        NA       NA     NA     NA        NA
2007-01-05     1     0        NA       NA     NA     NA        NA
2007-01-09     1     0 103.56380 115.3665      1      0 1023.5667
2007-01-10     1     0  86.91016 228.0697      1      0  857.3634
2007-01-11     1     0 116.00586 193.2930      1      0 1147.7385`
```

And my current code is;

```
Ind$P.Bal <- ifelse(IndTest$S.High>IndTest$H.S.Avg & IndTest$P.D.Up > Prob, 
                                Bet*TestInd$H.S.Avg*Spread-Trans, Bet*IndTest$S.OC*Spread-Trans)
```

I'm trying to get the below to iterate along the vector;

```
IndTest$P.Bal <- ifelse(IndTest[4,5]> IndTest[3,10] & IndTest[3,12] > Prob, 
Bet*IndTest[3,10]*Spread-Trans,Bet*IndTest[4,7])
```

Comment: ifelse isn't going to work here I think. You might for example try a for loop that performs an if/else statement on every row. Like this (I didn't verify it):
for(i in 2:nrow(IndTest)){
  if(IndTest[i,5]> IndTest[i-1,10] & IndTest[i-1,12] > Prob){
    Ind$P.Bal[i]=Bet*IndTest[i-1,10]*Spread-Trans
  } else {
    Ind$P.Bal[i]=Bet*IndTest[i,7]
  }
}

Comment: I've tried the above, however it gives zero length error; Error in if (IndTest[i + 1, 5] > IndTest[i, 10] & IndTest[i, 12] > Prob) { : 
  argument is of length zero. Code is:
IndTest <-Ind[1:10,] 
IndTest[is.na(IndTest)] <- 0
P.Bal <-for (i in 3:nrow(IndTest))
     { if(IndTest[i+1,5]> IndTest[i,10] & IndTest[i,12] > Prob)
      {P.Bal[i+1] = Bet*IndTest[i,10]*Spread-Trans}
         else {P.Bal[i+1] = Bet*IndTest[i,7]*Spread-Trans}}